# Find $x,y,z$ satisfying $x(y+z-x)=68-2x^2$, $y(z+x-y)=102-2y^2$, $z(x+y-z)=119-2z^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Solve for $x,y,z$:

$$x(y+z-x)=68-2x^2$$
$$y(z+x-y)=102-2y^2$$
$$z(x+y-z)=119-2z^2$$

After some manipulation, I obtain

$$xy+xz=68-x^2$$
$$yz+xy=102-y^2$$
$$xz+yz=119-z^2$$

After combining equations, I get

$$y=\frac{-51-x^2+z^2}{x-z}$$

This seems too tedious. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your system is equivalent to
\begin{align}
x(y+z+x)&=68\\
y(z+x+y)&=102\\
z(x+y+z)&=119.
\end{align}
Therefore, in effect, you have
\begin{align}
xa&=68\\
ya&=102\\
za&=119\\
a&=x+y+z.
\end{align}
This means that
$$a=\frac{68}{a}+\frac{102}{a}+\frac{119}{a}$$
or $$a^2=68+102+119\implies a=\pm 17,$$
which results in either $x= 4, y=6, z=7$ or $x=-4, y=-6, z=-7.$ (Thanks to paw88789 for pointing this out).

Comment: $(-4,-6,-7)$ is also a solution.

Comment: how do you conclude that $a^2=68+102+119$?

Comment: Thanks @paw88789 for pointing that out. I always forget about the negative roots.

Comment: You can also sum the 3 lines together to get $a^2=68+102+119$

Comment: @zwim thanks that's what I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 2):

If you add
$$xy+xz=68-x^2$$
$$yz+xy=102-y^2$$
$$xz+yz=119-z^2$$
you get $(x+y+z)^2=17^2$, and so $x+y+z=\pm 17$. If you substitute $x+y=\pm 17-z$ in the third of your equation, you get $\pm 17 z=119$, and so $z=7$ or $z=-7$; now it is easy to get the two solution $x=4$, $y=6$, $z=7$ and $x=-4$, $y=-6$, $z=-7$.

Answer (score 1):

> Solve for $x,y,z$:

> $$x(y+z-x)=68-2x^2$$
> $$y(z+x-y)=102-2y^2$$
> $$z(x+y-z)=119-2z^2$$

$$x(x + y + z) = 68 - 2x^2 + 2x^2 = 68. \tag1$$

Similarly, $$y(x + y + z) = 102. \tag2 $$

$$z(x + y + z) = 119. \tag3 $$

Therefore, $$x::y::z = 68::102::119.\tag4 $$

You can use (4) above to eliminate (for example) the $x,y$ variables, expressing both of them in terms of $z$.  Then, if the system is solvable, routine methods should conquer the original equations.

Comment: Or eliminate them all, having $x=68c, y=102c, z=119c,$ getting a  simpler equation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Got me.  Originally, I didn't think of that.  Then, once I saw the other answer, I didn't want to plagiarize.